# how to define the admin_user to delete posts? Ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get admins to be able to delete postings by users. 
This is the code I'm using inside post.html.erb

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
    <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete %>
  <% end %>
```

This is what I have inside the controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy
  before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy


def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

    def correct_user
      @post = current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path if @post.nil?
    end
```

I'm able to get it working for correct_user, but not for admin. I get this error message

```
undefined local variable or method `admin_user' for #<PostsController:0x5fda230>
```

I tried to def admin_user as user.id ==1
    private

```
def admin_user?
      current_user && current_user.id == 1
    end
```

But I'm experiencing the same error message.

Comment: before_filter :admin_user?, only: :destroy. You forgot question mark

Comment: If I'm not mistaking if admin_user? returns false nothing will happen. You have to redirect, raise error or smth else. By the way why don't you use CanCan, Declarative Authorization or smth like that instead

Comment: I tried with before_filter :admin_user? but while the error message is gone, the post doesn't get deleted. It just refreshes and the post is still there.

Comment: and I know that the account I'm logged in as is the admin account so it should return true

Comment: I added answer. It's difficult to write it in comments

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting the same outcome. It redirects to the root without deleting the post

Comment: It seems like that error is somwhere else. Is @post being loaded? Maybe this line "redirect_to root_path if @post.nil?" in "correct_user" method is redirecting?

Comment: Are there any other files that I need to look into? Or is the code I had above enough? Not sure why it just redirects to the root without delete

Comment: Check all methods in PostsController and ApplicationController that are called from before_filter on destroy action, e.g. "before_filter", "before_filter, only: :destroy", "before_filter, except: :anything_but_not_destroy". Also you can make simplest test whether "destroy" method is being executed or some another method is redirecting: add "raise 'Error from destroy action!'" between "@post.destroy" and "redirect_to root_path" and see is this error being rised

Comment: Is post you are trying to delete belongs to current_user?

Comment: This is the post model:  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

Comment: I mean this two lines @post = current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id]) redirect_to root_path if @post.nil? . current_user.posts.find_by_id will look for post that belongs to current user

Comment: no, the post the admin is trying to delete doesn't belong to the current user if I'm understanding it correctly. It currently works for people when they want to delete their own posts... but I want the admin_user to be able to delete other people's post. Does that line need to be changed?

Comment: In that case current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id]) returns nil and next line redirects. Try to change it to 
"@post = current_user.admin? ? Post.find_by_id(params[:id]) : current_user.posts.find_by_id(params[:id])". 
Actually you can use "find" instead of "find_by_id" that will result in 404 page if record not found. You can easily find information about difference between "find" and "find_by_".

Comment: In comments above I suggested you use Declarative Authorization or CanCan. All this stuff is implemented there. I personally prefer Declarative Authorization and find it more powerful

Comment: can you update your answer with the new code? I tried copying it into my file but I think some syntax was off

Answer (score 0):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def admin_user?
    unless current_user && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_url
      return false
    end
  end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user
  # before_filter :admin_user?, only: :destroy
  before_filter :load_post, :only: :destroy

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private
    def load_post
      @post = current_user.admin? ? Post.find(params[:id]) : current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

UPD:

As I understood from comments you want users to be able to destroy their own posts and admin to be able to destroy any posts. In this case you don't have to check is user admin in before_filter, e.g. remove this line:

```
before_filter :admin_user?, only: :destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy

class ApplicationController
  def admin_user?
    if current_user && current_user.id == 1
      return true
    else 
      redirect_to root_url, :error => "Admin only"
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Since admin_user? is called from any controller so put it in application controller

Comment: that gives me my original error: undefined local variable or method `admin_user' for #<PostsController